# What Boolean variable addresses the Nth bar in the past?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In a simplified case, I would like to define a non-series Boolean variable that returns with `true` value on the bar 10 minutes ago, `close[10]`, we could say, (on 1-min chart, I can handle that).

I have a suspicion that it's too obvious but no idea how to define a Boolean expression that was true 10 candles ago but not a series.

```
bgcolor(ThatBooleanVariable ? color.red : na)
```

So I'd like to see a red vertical line (bgcolor) on the candle that was 10 minutes ago but not earlier and not later. I tried to play with `timestamp()` function but no success…

Comment: It sounds like you want a function, not a variable. That function would accept `n`, and produce the boolean you need. Then the direct function definition is pretty easy: `n > TEN_CANDLES`.

Comment: Uhh, sounds right but defining and using functions are outside my practice. Could you please show how to define such function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to color the background of a candle 10 minutes ago on a specific date on 1m timefram, you can do so by verifying that the time 10 minutes ago equals the time you want and then using the offset in the function bgcomor().

```
ThatBooleanVariable = time[10] == timestamp("your time here")

bgcolor(ThatBooleanVariable ? color.red : na, offset = -10)
```

Comment: Hm, that would truly too obvioius, yes. :) Tried (to be sure) with "time[10] == timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, hour, minute)" but it's never true. Past ≠ present. Thank you for the idea. :)

Comment: Btw the opposite is always true. time == timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, hour, minute)[10]